# Alexa custom skill - handler to internally invoke other skills

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to develop a custom skill which would perform the below operation:

```
Alexa, launch michael jackson app
```

Then I would provide option for user to select from the below option:

```
Alexa, play music on spotify(and I need to internally pass the value of artist (mj))

Alexa, play music on pandora(and I need to internally pass the value of artist (mj))

Alexa, play music on podcast(and I need to internally pass the value of artist (mj))
```

User can specify mj on Spotify, iMusic and Pandora etc..

Is this doable?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot invoke Alexa again like 'Alexa, play music on Spotify' when one session is going on. There is one custom solution you can do that too only if other services (like Spotify) has exposed a REST API to use. If they have a REST API then what you can do is, after opening your skill (Alexa, launch Michael Jackson app) you can give options to user like below,

```
say 1 to play music on Spotify
say 2 play music on Pandora
say 2 play music on podcast
```

One user responds with numbers ( 1, 2, 3 etc.) then you can another input from the user for the artist name. Now call the corresponding API according to user input.

Please note all these logic would be possible only if another party has exposed a REST API.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done in several ways. One would require that your app respond to the launch request, and also 3 intents:

1. "Alexa, open Michael Jackson app" would launch your app. It should respond to the launch request with something like "where would you like me to play Michael Jackson? You can say spotify, pandora, or podcast"
2. SpotifyIntent: "play music on Spotify" or even just "Spotify"
3. PandoraIntent: "play music on Pandora" or even just "Pandora"
4. PodcastIntent: "play music on podcast" or even just "podcast".

Your intent handlers would then need to make the REST calls to the selected service.

This could also be done using slots, but I think the above is about the simplest way to accomplish what you describe.